# How do you hide closed tasks in the Azure DevOps boards?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

When using the Azure DevOps boards eventually after a project has been running for a while you end up with 100's of tasks in the closed section and a handful in all the others.  How can you hide the closed tasks/stories/whatever after a week/2 weeks/some time period so they dont clog up the rest of the board?

I cant see any settings in the board settings to control this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Which process are you using in your organization?  You can find it in "Organization Settings->Boards->Process".  I'm assuming you're looking at the Organization/Project/Boards/Boards.  On our board we have hundreds/thousands of closed items but there are only ~20 showing, with a "Show more items" link at the bottom.  It's also possible to remove the "Closed" column entirely if it's causing a problem, but that doesn't sound ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The Closed column only shows the last 20 closed items, there's a "Show more items" button at the bottom of the list of closed items to expand that out.

Your only real option is to collapse the Closed column by clicking the `<` to the right of the column

[image]

It has been asked on the developer community, but Microsoft state this is by design

> Thank you for your feedback. Closed work items will show in board Closed column. This is by design.
>
> According to the document which you point out, it says the closed work items don't appear on the backlog and do appear in the last column of the Kanban board.
>
> In default, the first and the last column only show 20 work items and with a Show more items link in the bottom.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/closed-work-items-still-visible-in-the-board/477641

Comment: Is the 20 hardcoded or is it something I can change?